# How to get my all data when my mobile screen was broken

Tags: backup, broken-screen, sony-xperia-z

How to get my all data(Like contacts,messages,files,etc) when my mobile screen was broken.

I am used sony xperia z.And I loss my mobile display by some reason.

My phone still working,but can't see any thing on screen.

call was incoming.

But when I connect my phone with my pc via xperia component .then it's show message like .B'coze I was add Patten lock in my mobile.

Please help me

How can I get all my data.

**I can't do any thing with my phone but my phone is still working**

[image]

Comment: Starting point: our [broken-screen tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info).

Comment: @lzzy any other way to get my data??Please  help me if it's possible.

Comment: If I knew something else I'd posted an answer – and linked it to the tag-wiki. Sorry, but no: I don't use Google Services Framework on my devices, and thus also not that Device Manager. No experience with that hence.